# Shrink/Fatten: offset and proportional size values

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I'm trying to use shrink/fatten tool for a 3D model in engineering.

- what is the unit for the "offset" value? Is that a unit length or a relative measure? How can I modify the units?
- what does the "proportional Size" value indicate? If I enable this option and set it to 5, for example, what does that 5 represent in the model?

Thanks!

Comment: Units ae a factor or percentage of current size. *Proportional Size* is for using with *Proportional Edit* tool distance may be in scene units, I think.

Comment: Proportional size will be useful if you enable Proportional Editing in the tool options, so it will work like with Proportional Edit is enabled (but it won't be). It looks that offset is in units for the scene (if they are set to be metric then these will be meters)